# Android ProgressBar in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I visualize in my ListView rows with percentages:

```
______________85%
______________10%
______________5%
```

Now for each row would display a ProgressBar that by way of better understanding the data ....

I'm using ListAdapter, how can I do with a for loop? Have any ideas

Comment: do you already have the percentage rows?

Comment: yes, and the calculation in this way: 
    value = d.ente / totaleE *100;

Comment: i don't understand what is blocking you ?

Comment: I don't know how to set that value with the progressBar

Comment: I don't understand. did you not find this information in the documentation ?